# Calcular valor (R$) com base hora PHP

Tags: php, laravel-5

Preciso calcular o valor de um serviço com base na hora. Consegui fazer esta parte, irei disponibilizar o código aqui. O problema é que eu preciso fazer o inverso, calcular as horas com base em um valor disponível para o usuário, como por exemplo:

A hora do serviço custa: R$ 100,00. Se eu escolher duas horas de serviço o valor será calculado para R$ 200,00. OK, tudo certo!

Mas como eu posso inverter este cálculo? Tipo, o usuário tem disponível como crédito R$ 550,00, como eu calcularia a partir desse valor a quantidade de X horas que ele tem disponível para uso?

Código cálculo hora-valor:

```
<?php
$baseHora = 130.00;
$horas = "02:00:00";
$horas = explode(":", $horas);
$valor = $baseHora*$horas[0];
echo $valor;
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que isso é puramente matematico, meramente:

```
Hora -----  Valor
1    -----   100
X    -----   550
```

Se a 1 hora custa 100, então fará simplesmente 550/100, que vai resultar em 5.5 horas, se quiser exibir no formato de `05:30:00` bastaria simplesmente dividir as horas por hora, minutos e segundos.

```
$PrecoPorHora = 100;
$ValorDisponível = 550;

// 5.5
$HoraDisponivel = ($ValorDisponível/$PrecoPorHora);

// 05:30:00 ~ Deve ter um jeito melhor
$HoraFormatada = sprintf("%02d:%02d:%02d", floor($HoraDisponivel), (($HoraDisponivel * 3600) / 60) % 60, ($HoraDisponivel * 3600) % 60);
```